# PHPJasper - SubReports - Error filling reportResource not found at:

Tags: php, jasper-reports

I have a main report and a subreport working fine in Jaspersoft. (data from mysql)
I'm trying generating a pdf using PHPJasper (geekcom), but I have the following problem:

```
Error filling reportResource not found at: subreport.jasper
```

I assume it's just a problem at this line:

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

Both reports are at same folder

How to set the path?

Comment: You need to pass absolute path

Answer (score 1):

You could parametrize an absolute path to the subreport:

1. In the main report, create a new parameter, e.g. `subreportsPath`, class `java.lang.String`
2. In this parameter subreportsPath properties, search for "Default Value Expression" and write `"."`
3. In the main report editor/design view, click the subreport, find its "Expression" property and change it to `$P{subreportsPath} +"/mySubreport.jasper"`

Now, you can pass an absolute path to your subreportsPath parameter from your library code, e.g.

```
array('subreportsPath' => 'C:/project/reports/reportX')
```